# Difference in array objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am currently working on a CakePHP project and I am trying to access some user information. However, the subject of the question is a more PHP-related one. I would like to know what is the difference in the following two objects (say first and second).
I have tried to access the 'username' value in each one, and I think that for the first one it can be accessed as $first['username'] and for the second one it is $second['User']['username']. But I cannot understand the difference.

Finally I would be glad if you could indicate a way of transforming the first one into the second one.

Note: The following format is produced by a debug() function in CakePHP.

```
array(
 'User' => array( 
  'username' => 'askdjsakl',
  'id' => '53698b89-cb34-41eb-931c-1859749dad86'
 )
)

Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => askdjsakl
            [id] => 53698b89-cb34-41eb-931c-1859749dad86
        )

)
```

Comment: Exactly the same thing. First one is how you should write the array to be valid programmaticaly, the second is a `print_r($a)` of the array. Are you having a problem with the arrays you showed?

Comment: As I have stated in the original question, I cannot access them in the same way. The first can be accessed as $first['username'] and the second one as $second['User']['username']. Is the information posted above enough in order to find the difference, or should I post something more?

Comment: You should update with how are you filling the $first and $second array then, as it is, they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those arrays are the same. You said to access the first one you do `$first['username']` and for the second one you do `$second['User']['username']`

Since they are the same, your variable `$first` is pointing to the inner array. Or in other words, something equivalent to this:

```
$first = $second['User']
```

Once you have that line, you will simply be able to do `$first['username']`
So... somewhere in your script you are assigning `$first` to the inner array